# Close HTTP Request in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, httprequest

I would like to close the connection after recivinig Data, How Can I do that?

```
    Http.request( httpConfig )
    .then(
        answer => {
            // do something with answer
            // close the request connection
        }, 
        e => {} 
    )
    .catch( e => {} )
```

I get some data from an api, but if I try to do same thing again the api refuses to provide data!
in fact the api still makes communication successfully, but due to having an active connection does not provide data for second connection. and returns some unwanted data!

in `answer.headers` I saw it indicates:

```
"Connection": "keep-alive",
```

Comment: It would be useful to see what the error message is.  But, the Connection: close header may do what you want.

Comment: There is no error at all, but since the connection is still alive, the API refuses to provide requested data, actually I manged to solve the problem with logging out from API after getting data. but since this problem also would be resolved if I restart the app (without logging out), I am looking for a solution just by terminating the request connection.

Comment: I tried `httpConfig.headers.Connection = "close"` but it does not work for me.